# Explain how href with only '/' links to new webpage?

Tags: python, html, tags, href

I have this html code taken from a source page, When i click on the below link it takes me to the new webpage. I know that you need to have a proper full page link("www.example.com") move from one page to another.

```
<a href="/go/Internship/2432300/" title="Internship">Internship</a>
```

Could someone explain me what is happening and how it works?

Comment: It is very hard to answer with that scarce information. Where is this link from? There should be more code. But in many cases `/go/` is used as a redirect path. So the webmaster uses a script to make sure, that when a user clicks on a go-url it looks it up in a database or just a routes-file (if you use ruby on rails for example) or via an htaccess file for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a relative path.

Relative Paths

```
index.html
/graphics/image.png
/help/articles/how-do-i-set-up-a-webpage.html
```

Absolute Paths

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/graphics/image.png
http://www.example.com/help/articles/how-do-i-set-up-a-webpage.html
```

http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: Thats interesting. Thanks